# libcurl FTP get working directory to string

Tags: c, ftp, libcurl

I have an application which interacts with an FTP server using libcurl. I'm struggling to retrieve the value of the working directory. How is this meant to be done?

In my code I connect to the server and issue a CWD command, which is successful, followed by a PWD command, which is also successful based on the server output (pasted below). But I just can't seem to get that value into a string.

The code:

```
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();

struct curl_slist *c_list = NULL;
c_list = curl_slist_append(c_list, "cwd foo");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_QUOTE, c_list);
int res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
curl_slist_free_all(c_list);

struct curl_slist *c_list2 = NULL;
c_list2 = curl_slist_append(c_list2, "pwd");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_QUOTE, c_list2);
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
curl_slist_free_all(c_list2);
```

The server output:

> > cwd foo
> < 250 cwd command successful.  
> * ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
> * Remembering we are in dir ""
> * Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
> * Found bundle for host: 0x1759878 [serially]
> * Re-using existing connection #0 with host localhost
> * Request has same path as previous transfer
> > pwd
> < 257 "/foo" is current directory.

So I know it's correctly executing the command. I've tried:

- setting a WRITEFUNCTION callback prior to easy_perform, to write the received data to a string. Result: with NOBODY set to 0, string contains the file listing of the directory, not the directory path. With NOBODY set to 1, string is empty.
- calling curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL, &dir) afterwards. Result: dir contains "ftp://localhost/", ie the entry URL and not the working directory.

That `remembering we are in dir ""` seems suspicious to me: in other posts I've seen people make on libcurl questions this is set to a directory path.

Comment: It looks like you pasted the code into the question incorrectly. Shouldn't the second command be `"pwd"`?

Comment: I think the info for [`CURLINFO_FTP_ENTRY_PATH`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_FTP_ENTRY_PATH.html) gets updated by libcurl when handling the 257 response from the `PWD` command despite what it says in the documentation.

Comment: @IanAbbott (corrected the typo). Unfortunately, CURLINFO_FTP_ENTRY_PATH is still set to "/" even after the `< 257 "/foo" is current directory.` response.

Comment: Although `CURLINFO_FTP_ENTRY_PATH` seems to get updated by `PWD` commands for FTP connections, it does not seem to work for SFTP (i.e. SSH) connections, so the documnentation is half correct!

Comment: Hm, interesting. I'm using FTPS, rather than SFTP, if that might make a difference? I wonder if I'll end up having to fudge this by keeping track of the working directory myself!

Comment: FTPS is just regular FTP with SSL/TLS. SFTP is a totally different protocol on top of SSH.

Comment: Forget what I wrote earlier. It seems the `CURLINFO_FTP_ENTRY_PATH` is only updated by the PWD done by the main state machine during logging in to the server, and not by extra commands done by the `CURLOPT_QUOTE` and `CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE` options.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for your time on this, for now I'll see what I can cobble together. I did discover that EFFECTIVE_URL is updated by some commands, just (apparently) not by plain CWD, so maybe I'll just try to keep track myself.